# How to search on project hosting sites

Tags: project-hosting

Say I want to look for open source iphone/Android tower defense game on sourceforge/google code/git hub. Directly searching by these keywords seems not easily getting desired result. Is there any way to search project on these sites? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Google.  Type the following into the search box "site:github.com android tower defense" to see what is in github.